# CKeditor in asp..net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

```
<%@ Register assembly="CKEditor.NET" namespace="CKEditor.NET" tagprefix="CKEditor" %>
 <div class="main" style="height:400px; padding-top:30px;">
      <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditorControl1" runat="server">
             </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
  </div>
```

I try to use CKeditor in asp.net and after I add reference .dll,I create this CKeditor but it shows the small textarea instead of the CKeditor which i hope. I use version ckeditor_aspnet_3.6.4. Is there any problem with the version ?

Comment: can you please post where did you get that code ? from where did you download this sdk ?

Comment: i download CKeditor from this website http://ckeditor.com/download

Comment: is there any javascript error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Just see after increase the height and width of your div => "main"  and check...